# grep: grep -v to exclude a file but doesn't work

Tags: linux, grep

I have three file in a directory:

**a.html**:

```
<html>
    a    
</html>
```

**b.html**:

```
<html>
    b
</html>
```

**htmlfile**:

```
this is just a html file
```

I want to get the files which filename extension are not .html, so the command I use is:

```
ls|grep -v *html
```

but the result is:

```
<html>
    b
</html>
```

why?

Thank you. but I don't know why `ls|grep -v *html` print out the content of `b.html`. if this command is print out the content of files which ending with `.html`, why don't print out the content of `a.html`?

Comment: That's not how regular expressions work.

Comment: The result is the file's contents or `b.html` ?

Comment: I can confirm this on my Arch Linux box, too, but am also puzzled by it. I suspect it has to do with the * being treated as a shell globbing character rather than part of the regex, but I'm not exactly sure why it's happening that way.

Comment: @palintropos take a look at Pumbaa80's explanation below, he/she explains it clearly.

Comment: Agreed. Recommend OP accept that answer, as it is absolutely correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you did not put `*html` in quotes, the shell expands your command to

```
ls | grep -v a.html b.html
```

Now, since `grep` is called with two arguments, it will ignore stdin. So the result is equivalent to

```
grep -v "a.html" b.html
```

which prints the contents of `b.html`.

---

*edit*

To make it work, use either

```
ls | grep -v "html$"
# Note that html$ is the regexp equivalent to the shell pattern *html
```

or

```
shopt -s extglob # turn on extended globbing
ls -d !(*html)
```

Comment: As a side note, why does grep ignore stdin when presented with two args? Is that a grep thing or is that something wider like POSIX?

Comment: @palintropos That behaviour is common to all `grep` implementations, since it is [standardized in POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/grep.html#tag_20_55_06).

Answer (score 2):

Use

`ls | grep -v .html`

this will filter out names with a `.html` extension.

*Quick test*:

```
$ ls
a.html  b.html  htmlfile

$ ls | grep -v .html
htmlfile
```

Comment: No that's correct. It's what OP wanted. Forgot he was using -v (invert).

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```
ls -1 | grep -v '.html$'
```

Comment: That is what OP asked for: "want to get the files which filename extension are not .html" - htmlfile does not have a .html extension.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I was confirming it worked because I'm sitting on a Linux box. Wasn't clear because I hadn't fixed my answer yet and I had indeed misread it.

Comment: I don't know why ls|grep -v *html print out the content of b.html. if this command is print out the content of files which ending with .html, why don't print out the content of a.html?

Answer (score 0):

This is something to do with shell globbing. I'm not sure exactly why `grep -v` behaves this way, but here are some similar results on Arch Linux zsh:

```
ls | grep -v *html
    <html>b</html>
grep -v *html
    <html>b</html>
```

Note those have the same result. The grep command is operating on the current working directory and using the shell globbing character (*) as an argument. The pipe from ls has nothing to do with it. It's included in the output, but grep discards it.

To see how this works more clearly, move up a directory and issue:

```
ls <dirname> | grep -v *html
    zsh: no matches found: *html
```

Edit: See [Pumbaa80's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11044453/1452106) for why this happens.